# Android - GPS Listener

Tags: android, gps

I am developing an Android application which consists a few activities.
I want to get updates from the GPS (`onLocationChanged`, `onProviderDisabled`, `onProviderEnabled`, `onStatusChanged`) no matter in which activity the user is currently using.

Where should I implement the `LocationListener` in order to get such a behaviour?

This is the class I have created:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{

private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location locationGPS) {

    //do something
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Log.i("===========================", "==============================");
    Log.i("onProviderEnabled", "==============================");
    Log.i("===========================", "==============================");

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    Log.i("===========================", "==============================");
    Log.i("onProviderDisabled", "==============================");
    Log.i("===========================", "==============================");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start the location listener on the activity you wants to start the gps. To start the GPS you can use

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener locationListener = new CTLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1.0f, locationListener);
```

and to stop the GPS you can use

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

Its better you write the GPS start on the `onCreate()`/`onStart()` and the GPS remove on the `onDestroy()` of a service and use that service. Otherwise once you stop the GPS the chance of starting the GPS again is less than 50% in some devices.

Comment: I need the data from the GPS in all activities.

Comment: @Udi I -- You will get the location updates on the LocationListener whenever there is a change in location on "onLocationChanged". For this you have to make a class say GPSListener which implements LocationListener and implement the override methods.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Service` and monitor location there or you can implement a `LocationListener` in a separate class and use it in every `Activity`, turning it on `onResume()` and shutting down `onPause()`

Comment: I have tried this approch, but I get the following error:  "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: Well, you'll need to show some code. It seems like you are requesting location updates from manually started Thread.