# How to execute method only when location of the device change?

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I have method "NetAsync(view)" in my app which execute on button click event and send data to my database, what i want is that this method "NetAsync(view)" only execute when location of device change, let say after 5KM. Kindly help me out how to do this, i tried a lot of methods by googling but they are confusing.

At the moment method "NetAsync(view)" executes on buttonClick event.

```
move = (Button)findViewById(R.id.movebutton);

        move.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                NetAsync(view);
                      }
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This link maybe the answer:

[Android - GPS Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138198/android-gps-listener)

you can add your NetAsync(View) in the listener:

```
 @Override
 onLocationChanged(...)
```

and more api docs, please find

[Android LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)